# How to use the ListDensityPlot/ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

all. I have a problem about the ListDensityPlot. The values shown on the graph do not match the real data.
The real data are all above 500K, but it still shows blue.
The data list and the plot code are shown here:
[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[z1, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{Automatic, {300, 800}}, LegendLabel -> "Temp. (K)"], 
 PlotLabel -> Style["5s", 20], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["r/R (-)", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
    FontSize -> 14], 
   Style["L", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]

Also, If I use the ListContourPlot, can I specify the range of the legend (from 300 to 800)? Because I want more warm color in the center.

```
ListContourPlot[z1, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Style["5s", 20], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["r/R (-)", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
    FontSize -> 14], 
   Style["L", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]
thank you very much

Comment: Please post actual code, not screenshots of code. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add actual code here. I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the range the `ColorFunction`.

Since I don't have the data, I have to make something up.

```
data = Join @@ 
  Table[{i, j, 300 + 100 i^2 + 100 j^2}, {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 
    0.1}]
listDensityPlot[min_] := ListDensityPlot[data,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {min, 800}}],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> Range[3, 8] 100,
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLabel -> Style["5s", 20], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["r/R (-)", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     FontSize -> 14], 
    Style["L", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14]}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
listContourPlot[min_] := ListContourPlot[data,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {min, 800}}],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> Range[3, 8] 100,
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLabel -> Style["5s", 20], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["r/R (-)", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
     FontSize -> 14], 
    Style["L", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14]}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

Setting the lower range of `ColorFunction` to 300, the center of the diagram becomes blue. Changing it to a negative value, e.g. -300, the center becomes yellow.

```
{listDensityPlot[300], listContourPlot[300], listDensityPlot[-300], 
 listContourPlot[-300]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really helpful!